# div with gradient background and rounded corners

Tags: css, radial-gradients

I've coded this `div` with a gradient background and rounded corners:

```
#pill {
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
    background: transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#080, #cf0 45%, #cf0 55%, #080);
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
}

#pill::before {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -20px;
    z-index: -1;
    border-radius: 40px;
    background-image: radial-gradient(21px #cf0 5%, #080);
}

#pill::after {
    display: inline-block;
    content: '';
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    top: -14.5px;
    right: -50px;
    z-index: -1;
    border-radius: 40px;
    background-image: radial-gradient(21px #cf0 5%, #080);
}
```

The result with Firefox, at top zoom, is this one:

[image: div with gradient background and rounded corners]

I'm not satisfied of the way I had to use hardwired values, specially for the `::before` element.

Is there a way, without jQuery, to make everything dynamic? I tested the CSS3 `border-image-slice`, which looked promising, but it seems to refuse a `radial-gradient` as border image.

Comment: Why not apply the gradient and `border-radius` to the `div` itself instead of using pseudo elements? Am I missing something?

Comment: The effect is not the same: a `linear-gradient` background is cut by the radius, while a `radial-gradient` makes a flattened ellipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More or less your requested result, but created with a shadow

You can play with the shadow parameters to fine adjust it.

```css
#test {
    height: 40px;
    width: 140px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #cf0;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 14px 10px #080;
}


#pill {
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
    background: transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#080, #cf0 45%, #cf0 55%, #080);
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
}

#pill::before {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -20px;
    z-index: -1;
    border-radius: 40px;
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle 21px, #cf0 5%, #080);
}

#pill::after {
    display: inline-block;
    content: '';
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    right: -50px;
    z-index: -1;
    border-radius: 40px;
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle 21px, #cf0 5%, #080);
}
```

```html
<div id=pill></div>
<div id=test></div>
```

Comment: Wow! I guess I've to read the whole W3C pages, rather than to stop at the parts I find "promising": the `box-shadow` paragraph is the last one of the CSS3 background module page at http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background :-)

Comment: I you read half of the w3c pages, you are doing more than most of the people !   Happy that it helped :-)